# How to change owner of Vagrant sync_folder?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, virtualization

I'm trying to create a Vagrant VM using Ansible.  I want to locate my website in a folder on my management node called "project" that's in the same directory as my Ansible playbook and Vagrantfile.  I want Vagrant to mount this directory as /srv/http/ticker on the (remote) VM when I provision it but I also want that directory to be owned by a "ticker" user:group as I do on my production website.  The problem is that the ticker user doesn't exist when Vagrant tries to mount the synced folder and I get this error:

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest.  This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly.  The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u ticker`,gid=`getent group ticker...
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u ticker`,gid=`id -g ticker` srv_http_ticker /srv/http/ticker

The error output from the last command was:
stdin: is not a tty
id: ticker: no such user
id: ticker: no such user
mount: failed to parse mount options: No such file or directory
```

I've installed the vagrant-vbguest plugin and I see it being run when I reload Vagrant so I don't believe the problem is that a "vboxsf" file system is not available.

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  # Putting provision here doesn't fix the problem
  # config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap-mgmt.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder "project/", "/srv/http/ticker",
      :owner => "ticker",
      :group => "ticker"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap-mgmt.sh"
end
```

Here's the bootstrap provision script that creates the ticker user:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo adduser --system --home /home/ticker --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-login --gecos "" ticker
```

I tried moving the provision directive before the synced_folder directive but it still gets executed after the synced_folder directive.  I suspect that any provision scripts always get run last and that's supposed to happen, even if I move the command around in the Vagrantfile.

I've read about a vagrant-bindfs plugin that will allow you to change the owner and group of an NFS-mounted file system but I don't see how this will help me if it gets run before my provision script.

I tried changing the owner of the /srv/http/ticker directory in my Ansible script using the file module but that doesn't work (and everything I've read indicated that it wouldn't).

I know I could just leave "vagrant:vagrant" as the owner:group of the mounted file system where my website resides but I'd like it to be owned by the ticker user so that it will exactly resemble my production server.

Is there another way I can change the owner of my Vagrant synced_folder from the vagrant user to my ticker user?  If this isn't possible, what does everyone else do when they run into this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks, the following 2 possibilities would work

1. mount from script

update your `bootstrap-mgmt.sh` script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo adduser --system --home /home/ticker --shell /bin/bash --group --disabled-login --gecos "" ticker

sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u ticker`,gid=`getent group ticker | cut -d: -f3` project /project
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u ticker`,gid=`id -g ticker` project /project
```

2. use UID

you can define the synced folder with UID and GID that will not change

```
  TICKER_UID = 106
  TICKER_GID = 111
  config.vm.synced_folder "project/", "/project",
      owner: TICKER_UID, group: TICKER_GID
```

This is referenced from the [github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/936)

**Old Answer**

you can do something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  # Putting provision here doesn't fix the problem
  # config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap-mgmt.sh"
  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.synced_folder "project/", "/srv/http/ticker",
      :owner => "ticker",
      :group => "ticker"
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap-mgmt.sh"
end
```

As per the ordering of provisioning, the outer scope will run before the inner scope. I did not test, I know it works for provisioning, should work for your case too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I still get the same "Failed to mount folders" error even after creating an inner scope as shown.

Comment: The first solution, mounting with desired owner, works but I don't favor it because it means that on all ups or reloads after the initial up, you have to remember to specify "--provision".  Alternately you can specify "run: "always"" but if you do this, you'd always have to do "--no-provision" on ups/reloads if you don't want to run provisioners.  I chose the second solution.  root owns ticker and dev with GID = 1001 is group owner.  I specify dmode=775 as a mount option and create the dev group with id = 1001 during provisioning.